# .NET 4.7 project cannot determine dependencies of .NET Standard 2.0 project

Tags: c#, .net, .net-standard

I have a netstandard 2.0 class library which depends on a number of nuget packages.

Next, I have a .NET 4.7 web API project referencing this project.

I now get a bunch of dependency errors, because the web API project can't find the assemblies referenced in the class library.

Before .netstandard I would have just set CopyLocal=true on the dll under references, but I can't find anywhere to do the same in netstandard class library

Comment: Package the library, specify dependencies in the package? Or do you need it to remain a project reference?

Comment: I had this question too, that is why always i use .net Framework class library

Comment: Like the other comment indicated, you have to give up packages.config and switch to package reference in Visual Studio 2017. Then the dependencies would automatically work.

Comment: @CodeCaster I did need it to remain a project reference, as I needed to update the class lib on every build in the project that referenced it, and I didn't know how to automate packaging and updating the nuget package on build. 
I chose to revert to .net Framework class lib - but I still had issues, and it seems it was a specific issue with system.ui.compression.zipfile